# Find height of each certain element and set it to it's parent

Tags: jquery, html, find, parent

I'm trying to set height of an `li` element to its parent's parent `div`. Every `li:first-child` has different height based on it's content. What I have so far is:

HTML

```
<div class="somediv">
<ul>
<li class="someli">some content</li>
<li class="someli"></li>
<li class="someli"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="somediv">
<ul>
<li class="someli">some other content</li>
<li class="someli"></li>
<li class="someli"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('.someli:first-child'), function() {
var height = jQuery(this).height();
alert(height);
jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.somediv' ).height(height);
});
```

Above function alerts height of each `li:first-child` properly but sets height only of the second `li:first-child` to all `.somediv` divs. How to force that function to apply height of each `li:first-child` only to the parent of that particular `li`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with second iteration of the `.each()` method, you are finding the both `.somediv` elements and setting height of second `li:first-child` to all of them. you need to use `.closest()`

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('.someli:first-child'), function() {
var height = jQuery(this).height();
alert(height);
jQuery(this).closest('.somediv' ).height(height);
});
```

This selector `jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent()` finds parent of both `.somediv`elements, and using `.find()` you are selecting both of them

Comment: The funny thing is I tried using `.closest` before posting question here and it kept giving me weird results. But now it works. And thanks for explanation the difference between both approaches. Cheers.